# HTML emails - Fit an image in a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I have a table with three `td` and each of them needs to have images in them. The width and height of `td` are fixed but the image sizes can vary. Goal is to fit the images without distorting in cells or image itself. Cannot use `background-image` property (sucks I know!). Here's the code:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td width="190" height="190" align="center">
            <img src="https://images.imgbox.com/fb/e0/53ItYqFd_o.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; height:auto;" />
        </td>
        <td width="190" height="190" align="center">
            <img src="https://images.imgbox.com/13/e7/pM2IjFYr_o.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; height:auto;" />
        </td>
        <td width="190" height="190" align="center">
            <img src="https://images.imgbox.com/13/e7/pM2IjFYr_o.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; height:100%;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried three different styles in three cells - none giving me a result where images get resized. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are giving different size for td and image. give image size equal to td. style="display: block; width: 190px; height:190px;"

Comment: Defeats the purpose - trying to achieve different sized images to fit in a fixed sized table cell without distortion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using - max-width: 100% and max-height:100% for image style. That will max out the larger value (height or width) to the witdh (or height) of the cell without streching the image.

EDIT: new to this...adding code snippet. Since your style is inline, I left it like that.

```html
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td width="190" height="190" align="center">
            <img src="https://images.imgbox.com/fb/e0/53ItYqFd_o.jpg" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; max-height:100%;" />
        </td>
        <td width="190" height="190" align="center">
            <img src="https://images.imgbox.com/13/e7/pM2IjFYr_o.jpg" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; max-height:100%;" />
        </td>
        <td width="190" height="190" align="center">
            <img src="https://images.imgbox.com/13/e7/pM2IjFYr_o.jpg" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; max-height:100%%;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great stuff - that's what I was missing. Very simple to achieve but having to do it in raw HTML and minimum CSS for email templates makes it difficult.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: The problem with `max-width:100%` is that some email clients will fill the full width of the image, even if it exceeds the table cell size. I would try `max-width:190px` and add width="190" to the image because Outlook doesn't use max-width at all.

Comment: True, but also if width of the image is fixed on 190px, the images that have width less than 190px will get stretched.

Comment: The max-width tag will still limit the maximum image width. Without the width="190", Outlook will use the physical image width which if it's over 190px, breaks the template. Other email clients will display the full width of the image as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be facing this problem because you may use the CSS in your project and the width and height there also..you may check thoroughly your whole CSS as well as the HTML...

Comment: It's a html-email, there's no external css

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
style="display:block;max-width: 100%; height:auto;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the. You can use `height: 100%` and `object-fit:cover`

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td width="190" height="190" align="center">
            <img src="https://images.imgbox.com/fb/e0/53ItYqFd_o.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td width="190" height="190" align="center">
            <img src="https://images.imgbox.com/13/e7/pM2IjFYr_o.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td width="190" height="190" align="center">
            <img src="https://images.imgbox.com/13/e7/pM2IjFYr_o.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```