# Is there an object-fit: contain alternative for email?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm coding an email newsletter and I'd like to show 3 product images from our database side-by-side. The images will be selected automatically and they all have different width/height ratio. I need them to fit a certain space so the links below them all appear on a single line. On web I could use something like this:

```
<img src="{{ product.image }}" style="height: 150px; width: 100%; object-fit: contain">
```

However, object-fit is obviously not supported in Outlook. Any email-friendly alternatives?

Comment: Does using background on a containing div instead of img help? (I can't test outlook myself at the moment I'm afraid).

Comment: have you tried working with table?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703044/html-emails-fit-an-image-in-a-table-cell

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Outlook supports background-image, background-size and so on.

I cannot however find a definitive answer to the question 'does it support background-size: contain"

If you have a way of testing with real Outlook you could perhaps try this method of showing the images. If it doesn't work I'll remove this answer!

```html
<table style="width: 100vw;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300);background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; background-position: center center; width: 30%; height: 150px"></td>
      <td style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300);background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; background-position: center center; width: 30%; height: 150px"></td>
      <td style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200);background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; background-position: center center; width: 30%; height: 150px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">text here</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">text here</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">text here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on outlook 2016.

Comment: @M.Qudah thanks for testing. I’ll remove the answer shortly